# How to make Flask respond in same HTTP version as request

Tags: python, flask

How can I get flask to respond with HTTP/1.0 to a HTTP/1.0 request? Or someway force a HTTP/1.0 response?

Right now I just do  `flaskext.genshi.render_response('tmplate.xml', ...data...)`

But when I do `$ curl -0 -XPOST ... -D -` I get

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: ...
```

back

I've tried logging `flask.request.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL']` before doing the `render_response` and that is indeed `HTTP/1.0`

Comment: Isn't this something that Flask (or Werkzeug) sets; that's your WSGI *server* doing that.

Comment: Indeed. I just now figured out that this is the work of nginx: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/112

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out, this is not an issue with
Flask that talks via Werkzeug with gunicorn. It the behavior of nginx: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/112 (and apparently an ok behavior at that)

Comment: Did you happen to read the info on the bug page? `That is, use of HTTP/1.1 in a response line by itself is certainly not a bug, it's standard complain behaviour. From your explanation it's not clear which problems this causes in your case (if any). If it does indeed cause problems, you may want to ask mailing list for help with more details.` That is to say, it's not an "issue" for the server to return `HTTP/1.1` when the client says `HTTP/1.0`: the server returns what it CAN handle, not what it expects the communication to use.

Comment: Indeed. "issue" might be a bit excessive a word for the case in point. What I was trying to say was "it was not flask that did the specific behavior, it was nginx"